# Parsing a JSON sub string

Tags: javascript

I have javascript function that calls an external Api and returns in  most case a valid JSON string.

```
function (successResponse) {
    {
       console.log(successResponse);
    }
```

However, in some cases it return the the following invalid JSON

```
Response: Status=200, Text: {"createdTime":"2017-05-08T14:47:56Z","lastUpdatedTime":"2017-05-08T14:47:56Z","createdMode":"API","uuid":"e333c1-3599-36d7-9ef5-dc22c79a4a52","userId":"anonymous"}, Error Message: null
```

How can I parse the above string to get the 'uuid'

Thanks

Comment: Which server are you requesting? If it's yours, better try to update the way the server respond to this endpoint, as custom-syntaxed responses are usually a bad idea.

Comment: Can you tell us the API link so that we can verify?

Comment: …and even if it is not yours, make them fix the server bug instead of working around it.

Comment: Can you post the valid json format and the invalid one? coz I am not sure if you are referring to the whole response including the status or just the "text" property

Comment: How is that JSON Invalid? Is the server returning the other info than just the JSON in the response's body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're expecting a response string in that format, you can use a regular expression to extract the "text" portion of the response:

```
function (successResponse) {
{
   var responseText = successResponse.match(/\{.+\}/);
   var responseTextJSON = JSON.parse(responseText);
   var uuid = responseTextJSON.uuid;
   console.log(uuid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can parse the string yourself to exclude everything outside of {} ?

```js
var apiResponse = 'Response: Status=200, Text: {"createdTime":"2017-05-08T14:47:56Z","lastUpdatedTime":"2017-05-08T14:47:56Z","createdMode":"API","uuid":"e333c1-3599-36d7-9ef5-dc22c79a4a52","userId":"anonymous"}, Error Message: null';

var apiResponse_fixed = apiResponse.substring((apiResponse.indexOf("{") - 1), (apiResponse.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));

var json_obj = JSON.parse(apiResponse_fixed);

console.log(json_obj.uuid);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Replace the non-JSON features, and then interpret as JSON

Looks like the server owner has been a bit lazy, and programmed an error response which contains a JSON-like interior section but surrounded by a couple of non-JSON elements.

If you are desperate to resolve the situation and have no ability to fix the server output format, here is my suggestion:

```
notQuiteJson = 'Response: Status=200, Text: {"createdTime":"2017-05-08T14:47:56Z","lastUpdatedTime":"2017-05-08T14:47:56Z","createdMode":"API","uuid":"e333c1-3599-36d7-9ef5-dc22c79a4a52","userId":"anonymous"}, Error Message: null';

madeJson = notQuiteJson.replace('Response: Status=200, Text:','{"Response": {"Status":200}, "Text":').replace('Error Message: null','"ErrorMessage": null}')

obj = JSON.parse(madeJson)

console.log(obj.Text.uuid)  // Result: "e333c1-3599-36d7-9ef5-dc22c79a4a52"
```

Of course this only works if the error message is always exactly this. In reality you may want to use a 3-digit wildcard to cover a range of "Status=" codes. But then you would have to also be confident that all the error modes produce the same non-JSON text at the start and end of the response.

#### Disclaimer

@sp00m and @Bergi, don't kill me: you are right of course, but this is just for if the poster has no choice in the matter 8-)